# TSQL-Sum all values of a column1 per one value of column2 and display ONLY one value of the column2 and the summed value of column 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to SUM all the numbers, regardless of what server it is from, and show that summed value per CreateDate.

```
[Message] [char](30) NOT NULL,
[Value] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[ServerName] [char](20) NOT NULL,
[CreateDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL

Message     Value   ServerName  CreateDate
ttl        1        server1     2018-08-09 17:58:00
ttl        1        server2     2018-08-09 17:58:00
ttl        2        server3     2018-08-09 17:58:00
ttl        3        server1     2018-08-09 17:59:00
ttl        3        server1     2018-08-09 17:59:00
```

so the result would look like this.

```
Value     CreateDate
4       2018-08-09 17:58:00
6       2018-08-09 17:59:00
```

if I do

```
Select sum(value), CreateDate as time
from table
group by Value, CreateDate
order by CreateDate
```

I still see repeated entries for CreateDate. I want one value of CreateDate and all the summed Value for that CreateDate value.

Comment: remove Value from the group by clause

Comment: wow...Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, remove the Value field from the group by.

```
 Select sum(value), CreateDate as time
    from table
    group by CreateDate
    order by CreateDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove "value" from the "group by":

```
Select sum(value), CreateDate as time
from table
group by CreateDate
order by CreateDate
```